# Logout automatically when token refreshed

Tags: flutter, dart, token

I have a problem here. I don't understand how to get the app to automatically log out when the token changes.

Following is the class for calling the API:

```dart
class Api {
  static String? authToken;
  static String authPhoneNumber = '';

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> postData(
      {String? phoneNumber,
      String? token,
      bool auth = false,
      required String urlHttp}) async {
    late Map<String, dynamic> responseData;
    late Map<String, dynamic> kosong = {};
    Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = {};
    if (phoneNumber != null) {
      dataMap['phoneNumber'] = phoneNumber;
    }
    if (token != null) {
      dataMap['token'] = token;
    }
    final url = Uri.parse(urlHttp);
    final basicAuth = 'Bearer ${authToken ?? token}';

    await http
        .post(url,
            body: dataMap,
            headers: (auth)
                ? {'Authorization': basicAuth, 'X-Number-User': authPhoneNumber}
                : null)
        .timeout(
      const Duration(seconds: 12),
      onTimeout: () {
        return http.Response('Error', 500);
      },
    ).then((response) {
      try {
        responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        if (responseData.containsKey('token') && phoneNumber!.isNotEmpty) {
          authToken = responseData['token'];
          authPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        } 
      } catch (error) {
        print('error ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    });

    try {
      return responseData;
    } catch (error) {
      return kosong;
    }
  }
}
```

I try to make this validate, but I'm still confused.

```dart
if(responseData['code'] == 401) {
 //handle error
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why you compare token, that is string, with response status of 401?

Comment: sorry, what I meant was that I compared if the status code was 401 which is if the token was not found. @Justinas

Comment: Please align your code properly to be readable and add the code that you tried. I can't find it right now in code sample

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have Exception models for different error-handling situations.

```
class UnauthorizedUser implements Exception{}
class TimeoutException implements Exception{}
```

Then throw these exceptions when arise.

```
if(responseData['code'] == 401) {
 throw UnauthorizedUser ()
}
```

Then handle them in the catchphrase part, for example, `rethrow` them and handle them in the repository layer or execute some logic when facing them for example when use is unauthorized redirect it to the login page.

```
class Api {
  static String? authToken;
  static String authPhoneNumber = '';

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> postData(
      {String? phoneNumber,
      String? token,
      bool auth = false,
      required String urlHttp}) async {
    late Map<String, dynamic> responseData;
    late Map<String, dynamic> kosong = {};
    Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = {};
    if (phoneNumber != null) {
      dataMap['phoneNumber'] = phoneNumber;
    }
    if (token != null) {
      dataMap['token'] = token;
    }
    final url = Uri.parse(urlHttp);
    final basicAuth = 'Bearer ${authToken ?? token}';
    try {
   final response =  await http
        .post(url,
            body: dataMap,
            headers: (auth)
                ? {'Authorization': basicAuth, 'X-Number-User': authPhoneNumber}
                : null)
        .timeout(
      const Duration(seconds: 12),
      onTimeout: () {
        throw TimeoutException();
      },
    );

    responseData = json.decode(response.body);

    if (responseData.containsKey('token') && phoneNumber!.isNotEmpty) {
          authToken = responseData['token'];
          authPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        } 
    
    return responseData;
    } catch (error) {
      if(error is UnauthorizedUser ){
        // handle unauthorized
      }else if (error is TimeoutException ){
        // handle time out like retry again
      }
      return kosong;
    }
  }
}
```

It's better to use await and async keywords instead of chaining `Future`. For handling errors [read this async article](https://dart.dev/language/async).
If you are creating a flutter application it's better to get familiar with application common architectures for example [this one](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture) which is very easy to implement.